# average of some frames / getting error using c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-streaming

I want to get average of 5 frames which their Itime are equal to 1000. What is the problem in my code? Why I get error in retur part?

```
float Data::HighestTime(float *distances){
        Mat mean_distances; 
        if(Itime=1000){
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                cv::Mat matDistances = Mat(width, height, CV_32FC1, distances);
                Mat mean_distances = matDistances;
                mean_distances = mean_distances * (1/5);

            }
        }
        return mean_distances;
    }
```

After Edition:

```
cv::Mat Data::HighestTime(float *distances){
        Mat mean_distances; 
        if(Itime=1000){
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                cv::Mat matDistances = Mat(width, height, CV_32FC1, distances);
                Mat mean_distances = matDistances;
                mean_distances = mean_distances * (1/5);

            }
        }
        return mean_distances;
    }
```

I got a new error:

assume that I have this function:

```
cv::Mat Data::HighestTime(float* distances){
    Mat mean_distances; 
    return mean_distances;
}
```

I want to use its returned value in this function:

```
void Data::Filter(){
  HighestTime(float* distances);
  medianBlur(mean_distances, mean_distances, ksize);
}
```

It complains that the mean_distances is not defined! should I define it as an argument to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your function does return a value of type `float`. You're getting a compiler error because what you are actually returning is `mean_distances` which is of type `cv::Mat`. Just change the signature of your method to `Mat Data::HighestTime(float *distances)` to get rid of that error.

---

Edit:

As to your second error. You actually have to save the value return by your call to `HighestTime`. Your second function should look like:

```
void Data::Filter(){
  Mat mean_distances = HighestTime(float* distances);
  medianBlur(mean_distances, mean_distances, ksize);
}
```

Comment: When you encouter an error and you want a solution it's always best to also post what error you're getting in your initial question.

Comment: @a_a Since it looks like you are a beginner you should probably take some time studying the basics of programming to avoid all these simple errors you're producing. This is not a platform to make others write your code!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider.

`Itime==1000` since you do not want to assign 1000 to Itime

Moreover, what are the `float *distances`? I think it is a pointer to an array and therefore, you have to increase the pointer and to dereference it with `*(distances + i)`

As you like to calculate the average, you have to calculate the average and this is done in this way:

1. Sum up all values: `meanDistances += matDistances;`
2. Divide the sum by the number of values: `meanDistances /= 5.0f` (Here, 5.0 is needed because you do not want to have integerdivison like (1/5) which is similar to 0)

Comment: do I need to use vector to store each frame or not?

Comment: @aa I do not get your question